# How to save more data into array

Tags: php, html, sql

I'm trying to save the data of a field in my "partenze" table in an array and then select only those data in the "arrivi" table.

Example:

Partenze Table:

```
id_bus,id_tratte,orario,stop_name
b1,1,07:00, NewYork
b2,1,08:00, Washington
b3,1,09:00, Washington
```

Arrivi Table:

```
id_bus,id_tratte,orario,stop_name
b9,1,20:00, Chicago
b2,1,10:00, Los Angeles
b3,1,11:00, Los Angeles
```

I select the name of the stop (Washington), I need to save all the bus_id with stop_name=Washington in an array.

Then I need to select all stop_name of the "arrivi" table where id_bus in ( array). Like select * from arrivi where id_bus in (array);

below the code used.
Do you have any suggestions? Thank you

orari.php

```php
<?
session_start();
?>
<?php
$servername = ;
$username = ;
$password = ;
$dbname = ;
$connect = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$request = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["query"]);
$query = " SELECT id_bus,id_tratte,orario  FROM partenze WHERE nome_fermata LIKE '%".$request."%' and orario is not null";

$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
$array = array();

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $array[] = $row;
        echo $row['id_bus'];
        echo '<option value="'. $orario .'"> '. $orario .'</option>';
        $_SESSION['variabile']=$id_tratte;
        $orario= $row['orario'];
        $id_tratte= $row['id_tratte'];
    }
}

?>
```

Search.php

```php
<?
session_start();
?><?php
//fetch.php
$servername1 = "";
$username1 = "";
$password1 = "";
$dbname1 = "";
$connect1 = mysqli_connect($servername1, $username1, $password1, $dbname1);
$request1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect1, $_POST["query1"]);
$query1 = "
 SELECT distinct nome_fermata FROM arrivi WHERE nome_fermata LIKE '%".$request1."%' AND bus_num in ( "$array")
";

$result1 = mysqli_query($connect1, $query1);

$data1 = array();

if(mysqli_num_rows($result1) > 0)
{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1))
    {
        $data1[] = $row["nome_fermata"];
    }
    echo json_encode($data1);
}

?>
```

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Are you trying to make dependant drop downs or are you just trying to get the related data? If the latter, you can use a `JOIN` statement. You are also open to SQL injection attacks. Look into parameterized queries.

Comment: Ex. `SELECT * FROM partenze a JOIN arrivi b ON b.id_bus = a.id_bus`

Comment: I'm trying to make two textboxes addicted.

Unfortunately the JOIN is not good for my problem, because from "arrivi" table I have to select only the id_bus previously had from "partenze" table.
Do you have any other suggestions?
Thank you for your answer @waterloomatt .

Link of my project: [link](http://www.clpbus.it/tst/index2.php)

Comment: Have you tried `SELECT * FROM routes WHERE id_bus IN (SELECT id_bus FROM routes WHERE stop_name = "Washington")` ?